# Defining the fields to be exposed (serialized) not via DataMemberAttribute

Tags: c#, serialization

I have an autogenerated class, which I want to partially reuse as DataContract. Since the class is periodically auto-regenerated, I wouldn't like to add DataMemberAttribute to its properties, because it will be lost. What are the alternatives? Can I define which properties are going to be serialized programmatically or, may be, via a partial class?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of tool is auto-generating this class?  Entity framework?  Linq to SQL?

Comment: Good question, because most tools allow you to include those attributes in the generation.

Answer (score 0):

You can add XmlAttributes at runtime with the [XmlAttributeOverrides](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides.aspx) class but I'm not sure if you can do the same with DataMemberAttribute, have not come across an equivalent of XmlAttributeOverrides..